# react native re-rendered components multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-native, rendering

In react native, I use some component like audio player, header etc. Also, I use console.log() for debugging for component I put log in start of components :

```
const MiniPlayer = (props) => {
      console.log('Begain Mini Player ....');
    return()
    }
```

I got multiple logs, it's re-rendering is happening multiple time without any special event or state change.

app hasn't any issue and not working slow.

**Should I control this re-rendering or is it common in react** ?

Comment: It's hard to imagine without full code or at least a reproducible demo. Please post more code that explains the app structure and the problem clearly. Thanks

Comment: I guess you may call setstate or some useeffect? Need more code to confirm

Comment: Please add more context, like more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your given snippet, MiniPlayer will re-render whenever its parent component re-renders. It's how react works. If a component updates, its entire subtree re-renders regardless whether the children components need it or not. To control it, you can use `shouldComponentUpdate` in a class component or extend the class with PureComponent, or wrap your component with `React.Memo` if it's a functional component. Since yours is a functional component, we can make changes to your component so that it re-renders only when its props change as follows.

```
const MiniPlayer = React.Memo((props) => {
    console.log('Begain Mini Player ....');
    return()
})
```

More resources here - [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#shouldcomponentupdate-in-action), [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) and [React.Memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)

Also remember that using React.Memo is just going to perform a shallow comparison of props. So even if the values of props are equal but if the reference changes, it would still cause a re-render.

**Should you control this re-rendering?** Well that depends. If your component is a costly one which performs heavy computations whenever it updates, then you should control this, else it is not going to affect much, as the DOM anyways is going to perform a diff check to determine what is supposed to be updated.